# How do you use shell.run() in a loop?

Tags: lua, computercraft

I have one program that creates one tunnel in a strip mine, and I have another that creates several and uses the first to work. However, it only runs the shell.run() in the first runthrough of the loop. It creates a tunnel, then sets up to create a tunnel, doesn't create a tunnel, and sets up to create another tunnel.

I am running computercraft 1.5 in the BigDig modpack, I have not tried anything because I have no clue what to do.

```
for i=1,amount do
    shell.run("stripTunnel", length, strip*3, "1")
    newStrip()
end
```

It only does the newStrip() function in every loop after the first one, but it should do both everytime. It should create a tunnel, set up to create a new tunnel for "amount" times.

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do... Do I understand this correct: You have your program saved as "stripTunnel" and inside you have a loop that starts the program again (and again (and again (and again (...))))?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please read this page on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In particular, what's `amount` in your program, and what's the `newStrip` function?  Possibly that hard-coded "1" in there is making it look like it's doing the same thing every time?